# Why do I need to start ssh-agent twice?

Tags: ssh-agent

I'm on a Raspberry running Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). Im stuck with a strange behaviour. After booting, `ps -ef | grep ssh` says

```
    root       482     1  0 16:03 ?        00:00:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
    pi         605   555  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent x-session-manager
    pi         724     1  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
    root       780   482  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 sshd: pi [priv]
    pi         795   780  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 sshd: pi@pts/0
    pi        1038   796  0 16:06 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

If I enter `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` I receive `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` Same if I use sudo.

As read from other discussions I enter eval `ssh-agent -s` and then I am able to do ssh-add, **but** now I have ssh-agent twice in memory:

```
    root       482     1  0 16:03 ?        00:00:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
    pi         605   555  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent x-session-manager
    pi         724     1  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
    root       780   482  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 sshd: pi [priv]
    pi         795   780  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 sshd: pi@pts/0
    pi        1048     1  0 16:10 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -s
    pi        1050   796  0 16:11 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssh`
```

- What starts the first agent? I've looked for .bashrc and .profile,
  but there no agent is started.
- Why can't I connect to the first agent, although both are started by pi?
- Does it matter to have the agent twice in memory? Is it good, is it bad?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You appear to have a GUI installed, the cmdline mentions `x-session-manager` so it's probably started with X server and separated from your SSH session.

Comment: Yes I have Cinnamon running. But all descriptions above are from the same terminal window. So i open a terminal and see that ssh-agent running (724), but i can't connect to it from this very same terminal. I need to start it again (1048) and then i can connect. What is the first one useful for, if one can't connect?